# are state sponsors of

Tags: nouns, attributive-nouns

a. These regimes are states sponsor of terrorism.

b. These regimes are state sponsors of terrorism.

Which of the above is grammatically correct?

The question is basically whether the first noun is used attributively or not.

(a) would be equivalent to : These regimes are states that are sponsor of terrorism.

(b) would be more or less equivalent to These regimes are sponsors of terrorism, and they are state sponsors of terrorism.

I don't think (a) works.

I don't think we can say:

c. These people are employees teacher of English.

instead of

d. These people are employees who are teachers of English. (.... employees who teach English).

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

"State sponsor" is a noun phrase. The plural of "state sponsor" is "state sponsors". Take for example the phrase "noun phrase", the plural of "noun phrase" is "noun phrases", not "nouns phrase". This is a fine example of idiomatic expression.

To confirm my hunch I did a ngram search and this is the result I came up with. To clarify whether "states sponsor" results are mainly due to "united states sponsor", I also put in "united states sponsor" search string. Admittedly there are other states too which sponsor other things too.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that variant a is not idiomatic.

First, I cannot think of a plural noun being used adjectivally. I do not say that it can never happens, but it would be inconsistent with the fact that adjectives are not inflected in English by number.

Second, I cannot specify a rule on when it is permissible to omit a relative pronoun, but it is not idiomatic to shorten the perfectly grammatical

> These regimes are states that sponsor terrorism

to

> Those regimes are states sponsor terrorism.

I wish I could give the rules that govern what ellipses are permitted in English, but elimination of a relative pronoun acting as the subject of a subordinate clause seems to violate the principle that a clause must have an explicit subject.

Your variant b is fine. There, the singular “state” is being used adjectivally to narrow the class of sponsors of terrorism.